# addEventListener for an element that is inside of a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form where I want to input something and store it. The addEventListener() method will not work when the button is inside of the form. Here is the code, html first, then JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h1>Enter words to display </h1>
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" id="wordName" name="wordName">
            </fieldset>
            <button id="addWord">Add word</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ch2_ex2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var wordInput = document.getElementById("wordName");
var addWord = document.getElementById("addWord");

addWord.addEventListener("click", fillArray);

function fillArray() {
    console.log("do something");
}
```

I find that the fillArray() method isnt being called. Why is this? I works when I put the button right below the `<body>` , but not from within the `<form>`

Comment: Post your HTML - also, what happens when you click? Is the form posting back and refreshing the page? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: @baao what exactly did you improve on my edit?

Comment: Clicking the button will refresh the page (because it will submit the form). Add `type="button"` to the button.

Comment: or return false in the form's submit event

Comment: @mplungjan: `return false;` doesn't have any effect in handlers bound with `addEventListener()`.

Comment: simply, the event handler is normally working, but you can't see it because the form is being submitted just after. change you `console.log` with an "old" `alert` and you will see that it's working.

Comment: Sure, the compatble way is to put the code in the form's submit event. I do not like addEventListener since it is not cross browser like onsubmit is

Answer (score 1):

here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/a54920a364df5ef864238c95b8eb48fa)

try this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var btn = document.getElementById('addWord');
  btn.addEventListener('click', fillArray, false);

  function fillArray(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('foo');
  }
});
```

}

Comment: why the huge fonts...?

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your button to the form submit button and prevent the default browser behavior. See my demo below.

```js
var wordInput = document.getElementById("wordName");
var form_el = document.getElementById("myForm");

form_el.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    fillArray();
});

function fillArray() {
    console.log("do something with "+ wordInput.value);
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    out.innerHTML = "you've entered: " + wordInput.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
     <h1>Enter words to display </h1>

    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="wordName" name="wordName"/>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Add word"/>
</form>

<div id="out"></div>
```